# Ignoring call to log screen view event with duplicate parameters. i want screen_view event everytime in android

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

`   @Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_NAME, "first_screen_test");
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_CLASS, "first_class_test");
    if (isAbc) {
        bundle.putString("NO_PARAM", "abc" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        bundle.putString("testCD", "1232");
        bundle.putString("testCD3", "1232");
        bundle.putString("testCD4", "1232");

        isAbc = false;
        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SCREEN_VIEW, bundle);

        Bundle b1 = new Bundle();
        b1.putString("b1_abc","abc");
        b1.putString("b1_test","test");
        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("CUSTOM_1", b1);


    } else {
        bundle.putString("test1", "abc" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        bundle.putString("temp", "abc" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        isAbc = true;
        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SCREEN_VIEW, bundle);

        Bundle b2 = new Bundle();
        b2.putString("b2_abc","abc");
        b2.putString("b2_test","test");
        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("CUSTOM_2", b2);
    }
}`
```

When first time onResume() called that time log of screen_view event is appeared. While our app goes in onPause() then after came in onResume() that time screen_view event is not triggering and show's "Ignoring call to log screen view event with duplicate parameters".